# Algum método para salvar os dados de um ArrayList

Tags: c#, .net, array

Antes de tudo, algumas informações:

> **=** .NET Framework 4.0
>   **=** Visual C#

Estou simulando um banco de dados utilizando uma *classe* especificamente para isso, usando um `List<string[]>`, porém, gostaria de ser capaz de armazenar e guardar estes dados até mesmo após fechar o programa, pensei em uma solução como gerar um arquivo **.txt** e quando a aplicação iniciar, ler esse arquivo e gravar os dados que estão nele, no `List<string[]>`.

Se não houver uma solução mais prática (além de usar um banco de dados, de fato), gostaria de saber como gerar esse arquivo **.txt** e como poderia fazer a aplicação lê-lo, se houver uma solução mais prática, qual seria e como poderia pô-la em prática.

Comment: Serializa a classe e salva em um arquivo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem várias formas de se implementar isso, por exemplo, [json](/questions/tagged/json) ou texto (*.txt).

**[Json](http://www.json.org/)**

Instale o pacote [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json), com o gerenciador de pacotes [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após tal instalação você pode a partir de um estrutura, um objeto, etc. gerar um `json` do mesmo e gravar em um arquivo com a extensão `.json`

Codificação:

*Serializar*

```
//objeto criado
List<string[]> objListString = new List<string[]>();
objListString.Add(new string[] { "1", "valor 1" });
objListString.Add(new string[] { "2", "valor 2" });
objListString.Add(new string[] { "3", "valor 3" });

//serializando objeto no formato Json
var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objListString);

//gravando informação em um arquivo na pasta raiz do executavel
System.IO.StreamWriter writerJson = System.IO.File.CreateText(".\\base.json");
writerJson.Write(data);
writerJson.Flush();
writerJson.Dispose();
```

Após execução desse código, você terá um arquivo dentro da pasta `\bin` com o nome de base.json nesse formato:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Desserializar*

Para fazer o processo inverso é só ler novamente o arquivo e utilizar `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` dessa forma:

```
String dataJson = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(".\\base.json", Encoding.UTF8);
List<string[]> retorno = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string[]>>(dataJson);
```

*Resultado*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**[Texto](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Txt)**

*Codificação*

Para gerar o mesmo exemplo no formato de um arquivo `.txt` é simples, observe código:

```
System.IO.StreamWriter writerTxt = System.IO.File.CreateText(".\\base.txt");
foreach(string[] item in objListString.ToArray())
{
     writerTxt.WriteLine(String.Join(";", item));
}
writerTxt.Flush();
writerTxt.Dispose();
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para gerar o processo inverso de txt para um objeto no seu programa faça:

```
String[] dataTxt = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(".\\base.txt", Encoding.UTF8);
foreach (String linha in dataTxt)
{
      String[] itens = linha.Split(';');
      if (itens.Count() > 0)
      {
         objListString.Add(itens);
      }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As duas maneiras são alternativas viáveis, mas, se fosse para escolher colocaria em [json](/questions/tagged/json).

Comment: Há alguma maneira de criar apenas um arquivo `.json` para várias `List<string[]>` serializadas?

Comment: E só para esclarecer, o `List<string[]> retorno` poderia ser substituído por `objListString`?

Comment: Sim, ai vai depender muito da programação, sobre a segunda questão retorno e objListString são do mesmo tipo List<string[]>, então pode substituir na programação sem problemas. A resposta proposta é um exemplo que se assemelha sua realidade, mas, claro você deve colocar em prática no seu modelo.

Comment: Só para ficar mais claro ainda, qual o melhor local para se colocar o processo de desserialização? No construtor da classe principal, talvez?

Comment: Pode ser nesse caso sim

Answer (score 2):

Você pode serializar o objeto para `JSON`, salvar em um arquivo, depois ler o arquivo e deserializar a string usando **[Json.net](http://james.newtonking.com/json)**.

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objeto);
List<string[]> objeto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string[]>>(json);
```